# Queue Append and Serve

Tags: c

Guys I'm new to queues and finding it difficult to understand how they work. All I understand is that a queue `Append`s items and `Serve`s the first item that was Appended.

From the code below, what I understood is every time it appends, the `Link` is always `NULL`, is that correct? And also when does `Tail !=NULL` become true? I'm confused because every time we append `Tail` is set to `NULL`...

```
int item;

struct Node
{
  int Data;
  struct Node *Link;
};
typedef struct Node *QueuePointer;

void Append(QueuePointer &Head,QueuePointer &Tail, int Num)
{
  QueuePointer NewNode;
  NewNode= (QueuePointer)malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
  NewNode->Data = Num;
  NewNode->Link = NULL;
  if(Tail == NULL)
  {
    Head = NewNode;
    // printf("Queue is empty"); //checks if queue is empty
    // printf("\n");
  }
  else
  {
    Tail->Link = NewNode;
  }
  Tail = NewNode;
  printf("Inserted number %d \n", item); //checks if Appends into Queue working
}

void Serve(QueuePointer &Head, QueuePointer &Tail, int item)
{
  QueuePointer Temp;

  printf("Served ");

  while(Head != NULL)
  {
    item = Head->Data;
    Temp = Head;
    Head = Head->Link;
    if(Head == NULL)
    {
      Tail = NULL;
    }
    free(Temp);
    printf("%d ", item); //prints out SERVED 
  }
}

int main()
{
  QueuePointer Head, Tail;
  Head = NULL;
  Tail = NULL;
  item = 1;

  for (item = 1; item <= 4; item++)
  {
    // if(item%2==0)
    // {

    Append(Head, Tail, item); //Appends For Every Even Number Detected 

    // }    
  }
  Serve(Head, Tail, item); //Calls out Serve Function, See LOOPING, please refer serve function
  //****NOTE: the loop for Removing items is inside Serve Function

  getch();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are confused between `Tail` and `Tail->Link`. In a queue, `Tail->Link` is always `NULL`. But `Tail` is `NULL` only when the queue is empty. `Tail` is not `NULL` if there is at least one node in the queue.

A queue is a FIFO structure (first in, first out). Nodes are always added to the end of the queue, and nodes are always removed from the beginning of the queue. Hence when you append a node, the new node is going to be added to the end of the queue. So the most recently appended node will always be the `Tail` node of the queue. `Tail->Link`, its pointer to the next node will always be `NULL`, as it is the last node in the queue and there is no next node.

What is happening in `Append()` is this:

1. Memory is allocated for a new node. The data is copied to the new node. Since the new node is going to be appended to the end of the existing queue, the link of the new node is set to `NULL`.
2. The existing queue is checked. If the `Tail` node of the existing queue is `NULL`, it means there are no nodes in the queue. So the new node is going to be the only node in the queue; which means it's going to be the first node in the queue; which means the `Head` pointer should be assigned this new node. Your code duly does this.
3. If the `Tail` node of the existing queue is not `NULL`, the new node has to be added to the end of the existing queue. I.e., the existing queue's `Tail->Link` should be changed from `NULL` to the new node. Your code does this as well.
4. Finally, the existing queue's `Tail` node is set to the new node, as the new node is now the end of the queue.

In this way, the new node is added to the end of the queue. It is now `Tail`, and since it is the tail node, its link is `NULL`.

Hopefully that is clear. By the way, you have tagged your question `c` but the pass-by-reference syntax in the function header `void Append(QueuePointer &Head,QueuePointer &Tail, int Num)` is C++, not C.